# ReactNative Swift component: how to set the constructor

Tags: swift, react-native, bridging-header, react-native-component

I have been working on a ReactNative project for a week now, and I want to make my own Objc/Swift native component.

I followed the official documentation but I find it not that detailed. I can use a callback etc, and [I also followed this](http://carminedimascio.com/2016/01/create-a-react-native-custom-swift-component/), but I can't find what I want.

I want to use the constructor init() of my Class, but everytime I compile, the app launches and Xcode throws the following error:

`fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'myProject.MyModule'`

I've tried many things such as adding `@objc` in front of `init()`, but nothing works. I'm kinda lost.

My files (I am using Swift 3):

**MyModule.m**:

```c
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyModule, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(aMethod:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)

@end
```

**MyModule.swift**:

```swift
import Foundation
@objc(MyModule)
class MyModule: NSObject {

  var myFirstString: String = ""

  init(myString: String) {

    self.myFirstString = myString

    super.init()
  }

  @objc func aMethod(_ callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
    callback([NSNull(), self.myFirstString])
  }
}
```

**MyModule-Bridging-Header.h**:

```c
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 18):

Your module requires main queue setup since it overrides `init` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of. (*quoted from RCTLog*)

Please add the following code in MyModule.swift in order to fix the issue.

```
@objc override static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: The problem above is a missing ```init()``` function - not that it requires main queue setup.